# Reference for completely-solvable (or split solvable) Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_Lie_algebra#Completely_solvable_Lie_algebras), a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ over a field $\mathbb{K}$ is called *completely-solvable* (or *split solvable*) if it has a chain of ideals $L_i$ such that
$$0 = L_0\subset L_1\subset\cdots\subset L_=L$$
with $\dim L_i=i$.

Wikipedia also claims that a Lie algebra is completely-solvable if and only if the eigenvalues of $\mathrm{ad} X$ for all $X \in \mathfrak g$ are in the field $\mathbb{K}$.

Could someone provide a reference or a textbook for this claim?

Comment: In the WP article, that claim actually has a reference to Knapp, A. W. (2002): *Lie groups beyond an introduction*. Progress in Mathematics. 120 (2nd ed.). Boston·Basel·Berlin: Birkhäuser. It's probably a good exercise to prove it oneself too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followint the comment of Torsten Schoenbertg, a reference can be found in Corollary 1.30 of Knapp, A. W.: Lie groups beyond an introduction. Progress in Mathematics. 140 (1996) (1st ed.).